# Salesforce Case integration via REST API call

Tags: rest

I have two sales-force org (org 1 and org 2).I am insert a new  account in my org 1 now i want that every time a org 1 account created then org 2 will automatically update its account with org 1 data using rest API .

Comment: hv u looked into salesforce to salesforce : https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=business_network_intro.htm&language=en_US

Comment: yes i want this feature for my two developer org .kindly help me

Comment: This is called "Salesforce-to-Salesforce" integration.  Salesforce provides it.

Comment: how can i achieve this  ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own rest api callouts from the account create trigger in org1 to the salesforce standard api of org2. or alternatively you can [set up salesforce to salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_to_Salesforce)

> Salesforce to Salesforce is a Force.com feature that lets you configure two Force.com environments (orgs) so that they share data records in real time.

This Feature will allow you to sync records between the 2 orgs without the need to write additional callouts in apex.

Writing a custom rest api is something I would only do in a scenario where I have additional logic that needs to be executed or when additional abstraction is preferred in the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a custom REST API using APEX REST  or SOAP API with Apex webservice methods download the WSDL  expose it to the other system.

My suggestion is build a REST API using  Apex REST with @RestResource

Pls refer to this link below on how to create REST API using Apex and testing it out using postman/Workbench application.

https://forceadventure.wordpress.com/2013/01/31/creating-a-custom-rest-api-in-salesforce/

You need to share the URL with external applications to access you API:

https://Instance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/case/rest_api/

They need to send a request to you as {"case_number":"1234"}

Based on this account name posted it will query and send the reponse as JSON.

HTTP Class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/case/rest_api/*')
global class RestTestController {
@HttpPost
global static void getTestAccount() {

RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
String jsonResponse = '';
String CaseNo= req.params.get('case_number');

// No account_name parameter was found; return status 400
if(CaseNo== null) {
    res.statusCode = 400;
    jsonResponse = '{"response": {"status": "Failure", "message": "MissingRequiredQueryParameter case_number"}}';
    res.responseBody = blob.valueOf(jsonResponse);
    return;
}

// Get the list of cases that match the case_number sent in the request.
List<case> cases = [SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Account.Name
                          FROM case
                          WHERE CaseNumber=: CaseNo];

// No accounts with matching case_number
if( cases.isEmpty()) {
    res.statusCode = 400;
    jsonResponse = '{"response": {"status": "Failure", "message": "No case matching case_number was found"}}';
    res.responseBody = blob.valueOf(jsonResponse);
    return;
}

 // At least 1 account was found, JSON serialize it and send it back.
try {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    jsonResponse = Json.serialize(cases[0]);
    res.responseBody = blob.valueOf(jsonResponse);
    return;
} catch ( Exception ex ) {
    res.statusCode = 500;
    jsonResponse = '{"response": {"status": "Failure", "message": "' + ex + '"}}';
    res.responseBody = blob.valueOf(jsonResponse);
    return;
}
}
}
```

Comment: i want this thing using rest api only

Comment: Do you wanna build a custom REST API using apex and expose it to other org? or Do you wanna make an asynchronous  callout using an apex trigger?

Comment: I wanna build a custom REST API using apex and expose it to other org